# SQLServer - Select bool if column begins with a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I would like to select a boolean of whether or not a column begins with a certain string.

```
SELECT (name LIKE 'foo%') AS isFoo FROM bar;
```

Is there a way to do this without using an inline `CASE`?

Comment: Here is a good discussion of this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095538/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-boolean-without-casting-in-sql-server

Comment: Why were you looking to avoid `CASE` initially?

Comment: I was simply looking for a less verbose syntax without having to create a UDF.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No

There is neither implicit boolean CAST in SQL Server nor a boolean type

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN name LIKE 'foo%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS isFoo
FROM bar;
```

Comment: Would be nice if they had a `BeginsWith()` or something that returned a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You might not even need the cast depending on your usage:

```
SELECT CAST(PATINDEX('foo%'), name) AS bit) FROM bar
```

This will return 1 if the col starts with the text otherwise 0. No `CASE` involved.

Comment: Good thinking. Slightly obscure though, relying on how bit conversions work

Answer (score 3):

A `UNION` operation would let you skip a `CASE` statement by combining two result sets. In the first query you filter for all rows that match `'foo%'` and in the second you match all rows that do not match `'foo%'`

Something like:

```
SELECT 1 AS [YourBoolean], 'fool' WHERE 'fool' LIKE 'foo%'
UNION
SELECT 0, 'fuel' WHERE 'fuel' NOT LIKE 'foo%' 
ORDER BY 1
```

(Hard-coded example w/o target table.)

Comment: This would touch the table twice = poor performance. Just to avoid using CASE?

Comment: Yea, this isn't an ideal solution. But I will give him an upvote for answering how to avoid the case!

Comment: @gbn: I completely agree about the performance. I have no idea why the OP would want to avoid using a CASE but it seemed like an interesting puzzle to solve. @jcm: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a User Defined function that you can call inorder to check if the name contains foo.

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from what gbn suggested but I think this would be more efficient (but essentially the same thing)

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN LEFT(name, 3)='foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS isFoo
FROM bar;
```

Comment: Would be the same result because you're touching every row in the table. Generally the expression in the SELECT is far less expensive than JOINs, WHEREs and GROUP BYs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN name LIKE 'foo%'          
     THEN 1
    ELSE  0
  END as isFoo

  FROM bar
```

Comment: The OP specified that `CASE` is to be avoided.